# Searching a file, only return strings with duplicates

Tags: c#, regex, string, csv

Currently working on a project for a car park. I have a csv file which contains strings of information regarding car license plates. I have used regex already to return 90% of the license plates, however shorter personalised number plates aren;t returning correctly: ie "AA12" returns as "AA12BC" as it fits another regex.

Each string has two instances of the car license plate, is there a way to only return strings that prove correct for the regex and two instances of the number plate.

Code so far:

//start

```
        using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\user\documents\regdata.csv"))
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            string pattern = @"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}";
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }

            List<string> regExs = new List<string>();

            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}");
            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}");
            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}");
            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}");
            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{3}");
            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2,3}");
            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}");
            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}");
            regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}");





                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C: \Users\user\Desktop\usersNotes\plates.csv"))
            {

                foreach (var l in lines.Select(x => x.Split(',')[2]))
                {

                    string result = "";
                    foreach (var r in regExs)
                    {

                        Regex myRegex = new Regex(r);

                        Match m = myRegex.Match(l);
                        if (m.Success)
                        {
                            result = m.Value;
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                    writer.WriteLine(l + "," + result);

                }
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using the longest patterns first, and add the lookarounds to the shortest ones. Like `@"(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}(?![0-9])"`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a CSV parser?

Comment: sorry the ''string pattern'' shouldn't be included

Comment: Is the objective to get duplicates from a comma-separated values file?

Comment: The objective was to return license plate numbers, which so far is 90% accurate, its the shorter 4-5 digit license plates i'm having trouble returning accurately as they also fit other Regex

Comment: The file is comma delimited? So if you were to just read the file into a string and `.split(',')` it would split it into an array of plates?

Comment: Please add a few lines of the file in which you are looking for licence plates.

Comment: If the file has the license plates in specific columns, then you should parse the lines and get the values for those columns, not use regular expressions.

Comment: for example the license plate is "55BH"
the string it is from is "LX55BHV54HBo" but it is returning as "LX55BHV" as it fulfils the regex :::::   regExs.Add(@"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}");

Comment: I think your issue is more of how your data is being collected. Your life would be so much easier if there was some sort of delimiter or break in the CSV file. What if someone has a license place of "L1L1L1L1" or "DOPEFISH"? You can't expect to create a REGEX to adhere to all possible license plates.

Comment: Do you need add anchors for start ( `^` ) and end of string ( `$` ) to each regular expression? How do the regular expressions in the question cope with an input CSV line containing `,%55BH=,`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.  I went ahead and coded (I think) the whole solution for you as I understand it.  I made a Regex list rather than a string list; this way you don't have to build and tear down every Regex object with each loop.

Assumptions: (1) Plates never have " or , and (2) Plates don't show up more than twice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DupeOnly {
public partial class Form1 : Form{
   public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
   }
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
      string zRegData = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\user\documents\regdata.csv");
      HashSet<string> hsRegData = new HashSet<string>(); 

  bool tfFirst = true;

  string[] zAllPlateData = zRegData.Split(',');  //License plates don't have comma's

  List<Regex> rxList = new List<Regex>();
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}"));
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}"));
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]{3}"));
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}"));
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{3}"));
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2,3}"));
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}"));
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}"));
  rxList.Add(new Regex(@"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}"));
  Match m;

  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C: \Users\user\Desktop\usersNotes\plates.csv")){
     for(int Q = 0; Q < zAllPlateData.Length; Q++){
        if(hsRegData.Add(zAllPlateData[Q]) == false){

           //At this point we know it is a duplicate, must still match a check pattern
           foreach(Regex rx in rxList){
              m = rx.Match(zAllPlateData[Q]);
              if(m.Success){

                 if(tfFirst){
                    tfFirst = false;

                    sw.Write(zAllPlateData[Q]);  //First plate doesn't take a comma
                 }
                 else{
                    sw.Write("," + zAllPlateData[Q]);  //Comma delimit subsequent plates
                 }
                 break;
              }
           }
        }
     }
      }
   }
}
}
```